# How to vertically center action buttons in a shiny app?

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I have two buttons that I have horizontally centered in my column, but haven't been able to figure out how to vertically center as well. I tried using "vertical-align- middle." Here is my UI code below:

```r
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tags$style(
    HTML('
         #buttons {
         background-color:yellow; position:fixed; margin-bottom:50px; vertical-align: middle; opacity:1; height:50px; z-index:5;
         }

         #fluidrow1 {
        height:50px;
         }

         ')
    ),
    fluidRow(id="fluidrow1",
      column(12, align="center", id="buttons",
             actionButton("test1", "Test1"),
             actionButton("rmd2", "RMD2")
      )
    )
  ,uiOutput("uioutput")

))
```

When I tried to do the first button individually, using the following code:

```r
 #test1 {
        height:50px; vertical-align: middle;
         }
```

I end up getting a really weird looking UI with both buttons centered, but one is large and is the height of the entire column div.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by:

```
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
```

instead of `vertical-align: middle;`

So it will be something like:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tags$style(
    HTML('
         #buttons {
         background-color:yellow; position:fixed; margin-bottom:50px; opacity:1; height:50px; z-index:5;
         display: flex;
         align-items: center;
         justify-content: center;
         }

         #fluidrow1 {
        height:50px;
         }

         ')
  ),
  fluidRow(id="fluidrow1",
           column(12, align="center", id="buttons",
                  actionButton("test1", "Test1"),
                  actionButton("rmd2", "RMD2")
           )
  )
  ,uiOutput("uioutput")

))



server <- function(input, output, session) {

}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Mka, could you add a quick explanation for why display and justify-content properties were necessary? Thanks for your working answer!

Comment: @Nova Glad that it works! `display: flex` creates a flex container. `justify-content` controls for the horizontal alignment of items and `align-item` to define vertical alignment. This website has some visuals that help understanding! https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/